# combine multiple linux commands in one line

Tags: linux, centos, centos5

I am trying to merge multiple linux commands in one line to perform deployment operation. For example

```
nohup php 1.php
nohup php 2.php
nohup php 3.php
nohup php 4.php
```

I want perform all of them in parallel, it is possible in a .sh file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also do-it like that :

```
nohup sh -c 'php 1.php; php 2.php; php 3.php' &
```

**edit :** 
to answer your question, the process are parallel. you can verify this by writing the `ps` command.
eg : with the `sleep` command :

```
nohup sh -c 'sleep 30 && sleep 30' &
```

output :

```
 ....
 6920    7340    7340       6868  pty2    17763 16:33:27 /usr/bin/sleep
 6404    4792    4792       7004  pty2    17763 16:33:26 /usr/bin/sleep
 ....
```

**edit 2 :** 
Ok then try with `parallel` command. (you probably have to install it)

Create a file `cmd.txt` :

```
1.php
2.php
3.php
```

Then execute this command (haven't tried yet, but it should work). you can change the `--max-procs` numbers if you have more/less than 4 core :

```
cat cmd.txt | parallel --max-procs=4 --group 'php {}'
```

hope it works...

Comment: it's work fine but one after one not parallel, how to run all files in parallel?

Comment: when I run the php files and get the uptput I see that the files run one after one and not in parallel...

Comment: @user3083317, read what i've wrote : `you probably have to install it`

Comment: and it's possible to prevent print of the output?

Comment: This should work, the outpout won't be printed on the screen and the process will run in background :
`sh -c "cat cmd.txt | parallel --max-procs=4 --group 'nohup php {}'&>/dev/null"&`
Any idea how to close the putty session after. maybe with `exit` command at the end, I cannot test right now.
Anyway, if my answer helped you, mark as "resolved".

Answer (score 3):

In linux you can use `&&` to execute commands sequentially, and a command will only execute if the previous one succeeded.

```
nohup php 1.php && nohup php 2.php && nohup php 3.php
```

Edit: in case you do not want the error-checking provided by the `&&` operator, use the semicolon `(;)` to chain the commands, like this:

```
nohup php 1.php ; nohup php 2.php ; nohup php 3.php
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind putting them into the background, you can do that by putting

```
  & ;
```

between the 1st/2nd, and 2nd/3rd.   This will execute the 3 essentially in parallel.

&: execute in bg
; do 2nd command irrespective of success of 1st

Comment: The above should do this. If you check with 'ps' after, you will see 3 instances of php running (assuming they are long enough to take a few seconds at least). Processor handles that for you.